# In iText 7 .net , how to determine data coordinates

Tags: c#, itext

I have a pdf that I want to grab a specific piece of info from.
My issue isn't how do I get it, my issue is I'm not under standing the coordinates of the rectangle.
I get the x,y, height & width, but not as it related to the actual page.
lets say for arguments sake I have a business letter with the date to the far right and address to far left. How do I grab the date?

ex:
 (space space space space space space space space )  01/02/2017

Mr Jones
some Address
blah, blah, blah.

Dear....

When ever I have tried to reference where I think the date should be, I end up with an empty value.
Thanks for any thoughts and or suggestions.

This is just one of the tries:
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(96, 822, 72, 8);

Answer (score 0):

This is harder than you might think.
Content isn't just placed on a page.

It's placed on a box on a page.
Both the content, the box, and the page are allowed to have custom transformations, and rotations.

And then of course there is the issue of how the coordinate system is defined. The origin usually lies in the bottom left corner. But this is again something that can be configured.

I would debug your problem by implementing a simple class that extends SimpleTextExtractionStrategy. In the method eventOccurred you should see events passing by of type TextRenderInfo. Those events contain the text being rendered and the bounding box. Print out the text, and its corresponding bounding box. Then at least you know where iText thinks your content is.